# 1 IIS box, 2 websites, 1 JK connector, 2 tomcats on another box. How do I make them work together?

Tags: iis, tomcat, isapi-filters

I have one website on one IIS 6.0 box working with two Tomcat 6.0.18 instances in another box, working perfectly. I am using JK connector 1.2.28. I now want to have a second website on the same IIS box working with the other two tomcats (Lets say www.example1.com sending requests to TC1 instance and www.example2.com sending requests to TC2 instance.)

The issue I have is how do I configure the ISAPI redirector so that both the IIS websites (which are on the same box) run the ISAPI redirector and direct to two different tomcat instances based on given contexts.

I tried creating the ISAPI filter the same way I did for the first IIS website and windows does not allow me to create another filter with the same file (isapi_redirect.dll). Also, I can see that JK connector is already registered in registry and thus I cannot have two separate installations of JK connector to use in two different IIS websites without conflict.

Do you know how it is done?

Note: The IIS box and Tomcat box, both have one ip each (192.168.x.x series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it finally. When the time comes to install the ISAPI connector, just use the one that is already setup on the other website. ISAPI connector it seems figures that two sites are using it and most probably creates two separate threads that do not conflict with each other. I also figured that you can use the same ISAPI connector for more than two websites.